# Windows 8 64bit, failed to connect to internet through dialup connection

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, modem, dial-up

i am using windows 8 64 bit, and using MTS Mblaze Ultra (zte ac2791),
internet is connected through dial up (Using model named 'USB Modem FFFE'),

so its always get connected as wished, but sometimes even its connected and in network inspector softwares also show data up and coming, but still there is no internet, DNS Resloving not works and ping not works etc.

and when i uninstall model driver and restart pc and then internet work again, if uninstall some software it work again (not a particular software), i facing very strange problem,

can someone help me how to debug or solve this wired problem?
i have checked windows events & logs there is not strange logs, and i am tring hard on it since many days.

and i can say that problem is exits withing windows 8 64 bit,

**EDIT**:
is there any tool and can directly interact with modem and get internet from it and make virtual nic if possible,

or

do you know any good tools related to my situations so i can inspect my problem, and help me in finding bug.

Comment: Does this device have native 64-bit Windows 8 drivers?

Comment: devices says that its support max, linux,xp,win7,win8 32bit and 64bit, but i don't think so

Comment: If the device says it supports Windows 8 64-bit hat makes you think it does not have native support for Windows 8?

Comment: still i am searching a lot, i think it may be possible that winsock may get corrupted, i am in office now, at home i will check if resetting winsock works or not, because i see on internet that many users are facing same problem like me and those are caused by winsock

Comment: just wait for a few hours i will put all details informations here

Answer (score 1):

Sometime due session layer like basic protocols winsock and ip get corrupted that cause internet not to work, it seem like data is coming and going but not corrects packets,
to solve this i used this methods

run this commands as admin

`netsh winsock reset`

and

`netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt`

that worked for me atleast

you can also try uninstalling those protocls from nic, and installing again, which is 'Internet Protocol version 4' in networking tab